# Multiple Slider Extender on a single asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a problem regarding slider extender on a single asp.net web page. I am using two slider extender to show two groups of pics. One slider is working but second does not.
Please give me an appropriate solution.

Comment: I really don't know why people giving you vote up, can you provide anything from your code or the HTML structure so it would be little be obvious